# Camera : delay between takePicture and CallBack :

Tags: android

The first call works fine.

Why onShutter()/onPictureTaken() are not immediately called after **mCamera.takePicture()** ?

Below you can see in the LOG that there is more than **6 minutes delay** :
    [LOG_03/04/2016_**18:0000**] mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, mRawCallback, mJpgCallback);
    [LOG_03/04/2016_**18:0652**] [SHUTTERCALLBACK] Inside onShutter()
    [LOG_03/04/2016_**18:0652**] [RAWCALLBACK] Inside onPictureTaken()
    [LOG_03/04/2016_**18:0653**] [JPGCALLBACK] Inside onPictureTaken()

The good point is that the photo is taken every hour thanks to AlarmManager.
But it would be better to have no delay or a shorter delay.

(Target API level 17 - HUAWEI Y330 - Android v4.2.2 (Jelly Bean))

More information :
Works fine on Sony Xperia Z3 (SDK 22 / Android 5.1.1)
[LOG_04/04/2016_**19:0000**] mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, mRawCallback, mJpgCallback);
[LOG_04/04/2016_**19:0002**] [SHUTTERCALLBACK] Inside onShutter()
[LOG_04/04/2016_**19:0002**] [RAWCALLBACK] Inside onPictureTaken()
[LOG_04/04/2016_**19:0003**] [JPGCALLBACK] Inside onPictureTaken()

Comment: If it is in response to an alarm the device might go to sleep after you call `takePicture()` and before the callback. Does the delay still happen if the screen is on?

Comment: @Timmmm : Thanks, interesting answer, I will try it with the screen on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you say it is being called in `AlarmManager`.. is your phone sleeping/locked at time it tries to take photo?

AlarmManager will run on next convienience. NOT straight away.

See below for quote/docs.

Note that your device might well be API 17 but your target API is likely API 19 or above.

From the docs: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time, but may be deferred and delivered some time later. The OS will use this policy in order to "batch" alarms together across the entire system, minimizing the number of times the device needs to "wake up" and minimizing battery use. In general, alarms scheduled in the near future will not be deferred as long as alarms scheduled far in the future.
>   With the new batching policy, delivery ordering guarantees are not as strong as they were previously. If the application sets multiple alarms, it is possible that these alarms' actual delivery ordering may not match the order of their requested delivery times. If your application has strong ordering requirements there are other APIs that you can use to get the necessary behavior; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).
>
> Applications whose **targetSdkVersion** is before API 19 will continue to get the previous alarm behavior: all of their scheduled alarms will be treated as exact.

The solution to this is to either target below API 19. Or, preferably, accept the fact you cant take a picture while sleeping, and go on a design principle that it will execute on wake-up.

Comment: yes the phone is sleeping when it tries to take photo (except for the first photo which doesn't have the delay problem....it confirms your point!) . My device is API_17 and targetSdkVersion="19" in my manifest.

Comment: @Beninho The solution to this is to either target below API 19. Or, preferably, accept the fact you cant take a picture while sleeping, and go on a design principle that it will execute on wake-up.

Comment: thanks for your help. I know understand why I had a problem

Comment: @Beninho Glad to hear it. Please mark my answer as correct if you feel it is. And/or Upvote if it helped. Thanks :)